# How to network two locations through 130m of trees

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I want to network two locations. Their physical distance is around 130m (418 feet) and it is covered with trees. The target link speed should be at least 10Mbit.

I have considered using UTP but its max distance is around 90-100m, also it is not possible to add a switch in the middle, in order to clear/increase the signal.

I am thinking of a WiFi solution using directional antennas with high gain.

Here is a map (from Google). The spots in the map are the exact locations where the hardware will be inside each building, so it is not possible to set the antennas far from there.

[image: map]

Also, note that trees are tall and it is not possible to see the other side even from the roof.

Is it possible to link them using regular hardware (max budget 150€, routers not included)? If you've done something similar please share the hardware used.

Comment: A [optical fiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_fiber) outdoor cable could bridge the distance. But two transceivers, cable and installation costs would exceed your budget.

Comment: If both locations are connected to the same electricity system, [Power Line Communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_line_communication) could be an option.

Comment: The radio frequency bands that Wi-Fi uses don't go through trees terribly well. I doubt you can make that link for that budget.

Comment: Is there any way to get above the trees, like erecting some sort of pole on the roof of each building, or near each building?

Answer (score 17):

The Wikipedia article on [Ethernet extender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_extender) summarizes your possible choices.

> I have considered using UTP but its max distance is around 90-100m

That distance restriction is only for Ethernet.
You however are not restricted to using [IEEE 802.3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.3) Ethernet for the physical layer.

If you could actually lay UTP cable between the two sites, then you have other choices that utilize the UTP such as T1, HDSL, VDSL etc.  But those technologies typically use telco-grade (i.e. expensive) equipment. There's lots of used telco xDSL stuff on eBay. Or there are units like [these point-to-point extenders](https://www.blackbox.com/en-US/store/browse?cat=Networking_Extenders_Ethernet) for self installation in a closed/private system.

Note that xDSL solutions require only voice-grade copper.
If you want to lay Cat5, the 100m restriction of Ethernet can be overcome with an inline *repeater* powered by POE, such as [this](https://www.veracityglobal.com/transmission/category/ethernet-extender) although such a device would require weatherproofing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. However, it will require some work, and 130m of low loss Cat6e burial grade cable would be far simpler;  experience has shown you can get more than 100m with good cable, sans repeaters.

You will need two high gain antenna attached to the WiFi cards or adapters on each end. Each is very carefully aligned and solidly built (wind is not your friend) to point to a passive repeater, which is a pair of high gain antennae connected to each other back-to-back. The passive repeaters pickup signal and send it out again, aimed at the other passive repeater.

> PC1 -> WiFi card -> High-Gain Antenna -> Passive Repeater 1 -> Passive Repeater 2 -> High-Gain Antenna -> WiFi card - PC2

[image]

You're now on the verge of being able to use active repeaters, powered off solar cells with batteries, depending on the insolation at your location; but those trees look healthy, so I believe they're getting quite a bit of sunshine, no?

Answer (score 2):

If a 10 Mbit/s link speed is really acceptable, you could use 10-base-2: Ethernet over RG58 cable. The maximum cable length is 185 m so you have plenty of margin within the specs. Direct burial cable is available.

You will need to acquire two old Ethernet hubs, each with 10-base-2 interfaces. These will have one or a few RJ45 jacks (limited to 10 Mb/s) on one side and a BNC jack on the other. Of course, you will use patch cables to connect each of them to a port on one of your existing 100 Mbit or gigabit switches. (This will not slow the rest of your network to 10 Mbit/s.) Or if you have only one machine at the far end just cable it right into the BNC-equipped hub.

Then you'll need whatever length of RG-58A/U cable for the run, terminated with BNC male connectors; two BNC "tee" adapters (these will have one male and two female connectors); and two 50-ohm BNC male terminators.  The "tee" connectors and terminators are required. Do not simply run the RG58 cable directly from one hub to the other.

This cable is 50 ohm impedance. Do not try to use RG-59 or RG-6, both in common use for cable TV, baseband video, and digital audio - those are 72 or 75 ohms. They won't work reliably.

At **one end only**, ground the terminator to the building electrical service ground. (You can get terminators with pigtail leads or other connection points to facilitate this.) Don't let it float, and don't ground it at both ends.

A major concern here is that almost all (maybe all) hubs with 10-base-2 ports are out of production and you will likely have to go with either used ones, or new ones that are made for a very small market (so they will not be cheap). Should they fail, you will have similar issues acquiring replacements. On the other hand the technology is tried-and-true and you will be using it well within its limits.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10BASE2
- http://www.thenetworkencyclopedia.com/entry/10base2/

Comment: Personally, I prefer sawdust's suggestion of Cat5 with a PoE-powered inline repeater.

Answer (score 1):

Fiber is really cheap. You can get a 2 pack of gig Fiber/Ethernet converters for $37 ([Gigabit SingleMode Fiber to Ethernet Media Converter, Dual SC Fiber, 1000Base-LX to 10/100/1000Base-Tx Gigabit SMF Fiber SC to Copper RJ45 Ethernet Converter](https://www.newegg.com/p/2AS-003C-00162)) and works up to 20 kilometers.

I found 400ft of single mode fiber [on eBay for $25](https://www.ebay.com/itm/285459666045) (dead link as of 2024) You could probably buy the correct length of outdoor rated fiber and have them put the correct ends on it for a couple hundred $$.

I have been using fiber to a detached garage on a different electrical service with 25 meter of indoor rated fiber for the last 7 years and it still works perfectly. The whole setup with a steel cable to hang the fiber on, zip ties, and nylon mesh to cover it, cost me less than $40 as I got the fiber converters for next to nothing at a liquidation.

Comment: The question was asked 10y ago when fiber cables and equipment weren't cheap. In addition to your answer, fiber is pretty brittle and I don't se it surviving a small forest without shielding from UV and animals.

Comment: I've been running mine since 2017 and was cheap back then, its even cheaper now if someone is looking to run the same thing. A 1000 ft spool of outdoor rated cable is like $175 https://www.cablewholesale.com/specs/10f3-006nh.php and if you have a way of terminating the ends, you might get off pretty cheap. You could try and lay the cable on the ground - for the price of the cable, if it fails in 3-4 years, just run another one. Or rent a trencher for a day for $100. The cable TV company pretty much just lays the cable on the ground and it works for years.