# Recommended method of extending wifi to a new shop? (3 blocks away)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-extender

Our current shop is 3 blocks away from our new shop, and my boss needs internet for invoices, email, etc. We've decided to try extending the range, as our unnamed internet service provider says that we will be charged separately for the two buildings, and that's a problem. (Doubling the cost of monthly internet). To clarify, I'm only asking what method should be used to achieve this signal boost, not what to buy. Would a directional antenna work, if used on each end? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How far is this exactly?  While 3 blocks is specific, it doesn't tell us, a specific length in a unit which is easily converted to miles or meters.

Comment: Is direct visibility between these buildings?

Comment: 852 feet, but I figure around 1000 feet would be rounding up

Comment: Look into a leased line between the two buildings from the phone company (for a xDSL, e.g. HDSL or VDSL, connection).  BTW how is phone service going to be connected between these two shops?

Comment: A similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/616108/how-to-network-two-locations-through-130m-of-trees

Comment: @Hellreaver Well 802.11 won't work...

Comment: @Ramhound dang, really? That's my main concern, the shop is across other's property, as well

Comment: @Hellreaver - 802.11ac  has a 820limit, thats, with zero interference.

Comment: @Ramhound even with an extender?

Comment: How are you going to extend it 1000ft and 4 blocks?

Comment: @Ramhound http://www.amazon.com/Ubiquiti-Networks-PICO2HP-2-4GHz-802-11bg/dp/B004EPPJAI/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top, But I'm sure you're pointing this out for a reason

Comment: You going to start sticking those to random buildings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have unobstructed line-of-sight between the two buildings, this is practically impossible.

Yes, you want highly directional antennas,

Even with unobstructed LOS it's asking a lot of WiFi, especially for something that your business depends  on. This is particularly true in today's crowded WiFi environment: What worked passably well a few years ago probably won't work so well today, as there are far more WiFi users than there used to be. The old trick of going to channel 1 or 11 doesn't help much any more, either. There are already users on every optimal channel and all the sub-optimal channels too.

And then there are atmospheric conditions to worry about. These bands are open for unlicensed use because at these freqs there is heavy attenuation by water vapor in the air (so they're not useful for long-distance microwave comms... which should tell you something). What works in dry weather will likely stop working when it's humid, and more likely when it rains.

Note that the long distance WiFi challenges that happen around DEFcon are done in the Nevada desert: very dry air and essentially no other WiFi users around.