# ADSL modems directly connected

Tags: adsl-router, adsl2+

Is there a way to connect two ADSL modems together directly, to each other's ADSL port?

As far as I can see, this is not likely as they both act as clients, and there needs to be a server. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Assuming a server is required, what kind of system can I build to provide an ADSL service to routers?

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). What are you actually trying to achieve by connecting the routers in this way?

Answer (score 11):

> Is there a way to connect two ADSL routers together directly, to each other's ADSL port?

No, each ADSL modem/router that you have is a slave (or remote) unit.  They cannot work together (as you already suspect).

Communication links like xDSL are point-to-point but have asymmetric topology, that is, the modem at your end (called the *remote* unit or CPE, customer-premises equipment) is a "slave" unit, and the modem/DSLAM at the ISP or central office end (called the *line* unit) is a "master" unit.  (Do not confuse or conflate the asymmetric topology with the asymmetric connection speeds of ADSL.)

In order to use the ADSL link,  the line and remote units first have to perform a predefined series transmissions and responses (called *training*) to evaluate line conditions and set transmission rates, power levels and equalization.  Only after training is complete can the ADSL link be used to transmit/receive data.
Bottom line is that you cannot use an ADSL modem only built for use as the *remote* unit in place of the ADSL *line* unit.
You don't need a entire DSLAM (a multiplexer for many channels), but you would need a Line (or master) ADSL unit (e.g. Ethernet on one side, ADSL on the other).

> Assuming a server is required, what kind of system can I build to provide an ADSL service to routers?

Rather than ADSL, you might be better off with a symmetrical connection (i.e. upstream and downstream speeds are the same), such as a point-to-point VDSL setup.
See [How to network two locations through 130m of trees](https://superuser.com/questions/616108/how-to-network-two-locations-through-130m-of-trees/616467#616467)

BTW -- Your use of "server" and "client" are inappropriate.  xDSL modems use the master/slave model, not the client/server model.

Comment: Although VDSL is symmetric in the sense of identical up/down speeds, is it really also symmetric in the sense of not requiring different equipment on both ends?

Comment: @grawity -- I've tried to avoid such confusion by using "asymmetric" and "symmetrical" as adjectives for either "topology" or "connection" to remove ambiguity.  Apparently it didn't help.  I did not imply the *"it really also symmetric in the sense of not requiring different equipment"*.  Instead I wrote that "xDSL are point-to-point but have asymmetric topology" and "xDSL modems use the master/slave model".

Comment: @grawity -- There are VDSL modems that can be used at either end, but there is typically a hardware switch that configures the mode, either master (CO) or slave (CPE).  See https://www.versatek.com/product/vx-veb160r1/  So the *"equipment"* can be the "same" at both ends, but the topology is still asymmetric, i.e. master/slave.

Answer (score 9):

#### What kind of system can I build to provide an ADSL service to routers?

You need at least a [DSLAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_subscriber_line_access_multiplexer):

> A digital subscriber line access multiplexer (DSLAM, often pronounced dee-slam) is a network device, often located in telephone exchanges, that connects multiple customer digital subscriber line (DSL) interfaces to a high-speed digital communications channel using multiplexing techniques.

There will be other bits of infrastructure required as well.

For example, you will something behind the DSLAM that will route traffic between your two devices.

What you are trying do is to become your own ISP ...

Comment: Not quite my own isp, but make a small adsl local network to put old routers to use and network between buildings close by. Mainly just the concept of the adsl connection. It’s also easier to get an adsl router and cheaper than a wan router.

Comment: You can get yourself a DSLAM or equivalent, and they are not that expensive - especially second hand ones supporting ADSL rather then VDSL.

Comment: *"You need at least a DSLAM"* -- You exaggerate.

Comment: @DevelopedLogic You'd do much better with point-to-point wireless bridges.

Comment: @sawdust Exaggerate? Really?

Answer (score 0):

There is a device that allows running private VDSL2 between 2 routers. Its a set of 2 boxes that the signal can be run over standard phone line or Ethernet up to 1km. The boxes can be can be configured to server or client, so it *may* be possible to use one box and a VDSL2 modem. I posted a link to the device, but the post was swiftly deleted by "Journeyman Geek" as they didn't think the answer was relevant.

Comment: I dont see how this is an answer either