# ADSL emulation without dslam: is possible?

Tags: adsl

Using the right pieces(ATA+Asterisk, or Asterisk with analog card and two fxs modules) I successfully create a fake pstn and connect two 56k modems(Windows to Linux or vice-versa) to emulate the old good ancient internet of the 56k era. Using the right hardware is also possible to emulate a isdn circuit(isdn gateway + asterisk or asterisk + isdn bri card).
I have also the idea to emulate an ADSL, only for hobby/testing, nothing professional or serious.
The question is: using an hardware like the VC-231G

[image: VC-231G]

is possible to use two of them(one master, one slave) and connect two adsl modem in a p2p way(Linux pppd + Linux pppd or Linux pppd to Windows), maybe using asterisk to simulate the pstn?

Comment: pppd? Most ADSL setups run emulated Ethernet over ATM (which can be used to directly run IP over), so they don't need PPP like a dial-up modem does.

Comment: Thanks, I remind when I use the adsl to use pppd call adsl to make an adsl connection to outside, so i think I have to use pppd for a dial-in connection

Comment: Some ISPs use PPPoE (i.e. PPP on top of emulated Ethernet on top of ATM/ADSL), but that's mostly because they want PPP for accounting reasons, not because ADSL needs it.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1271928/adsl-modems-directly-connected/1271960#1271960