# Fiber internet via DSL

Tags: wireless-networking, dsl

I have fiber internet via DSL cable connected to ISP gateway. I have multiple phone jacks in my house.  As I understand it, internet is being "piped through" each one of these jacks. Can I plug a second router into a different phone jack and use it as a dumb AP, without connecting it to the main gateway? Is it possible to make this work by disabling DHCP?  Ideally, a router or range extender enabled in"AP mode" would be easier.  Would that work? I want to extend my wifi signal without running cables.  I do not have a landline phone so no filters required.  I am new to this and would appreciate any  help!

oEr

Comment: "*I have fiber internet via DSL cable ...*" -- Huh? Do you mean that DSL is used for the "last mile"? Assuming that it's a DSL signal entering your home, and you have a single DSL modem for that "*ISP gateway*", then you cannot add another DSL modem. All flavors of xDSL operate in a master-slave, one-to-one relationship. Your home already has a slave DSL modem. You cannot connect 2 slave units to a master unit. See https://superuser.com/questions/1271928/adsl-modems-directly-connected/1271960#1271960

Comment: Also, thy presence of a telephone jack does not imply the presence of the internet.  It depends on how it's been wired.

Comment: Thanks Rohit.  Yes, DSL is for the last mile and connects to one modem.

Comment: ISPs use this as marketing. It's DSL. DSL doesn't travel particularly far over phone cables, so the ISP runs fiber to neighborhoods, then splits it out to individual DSL lines that then don't have to go very far to get to the houses. Also, no. You can only have one DSL modem per line of service. You need to use routers or switches (or just a wifi router) to make the internet available around the building.