# extending ethernet to distant outbuilding

Tags: networking, ethernet, home-networking

I'd like to extend internet service to an outbuilding that is 600+ft from my house. The distance is heavily wooded, so I think a wireless solution is a non-starter (but correct me if I'm wrong). This looks like it could do it:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01BOD8C9W/ref=ask_ql_qh_dp_hza](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01BOD8C9W)

... the description claiming it can support 100 Mbps over 1000ft, using VDSL. (I don't need the full 100Mbps, but would like to have at least 20Mbps or so).

They also claim it works with "copper phone wire". It turns out that I have a lead on a long-enough spool of coax, for cheap or free. I'm wondering how it would work with this device ? Since phone wire is not impedance controlled at all (I don't think) and they claim it works with that, I'm not sure how 75-ohm coax could be worse.   I realize I need to wire it to RJ45 connectors at each end. I would probably just lay the line along the forest floor (the way I do with low-voltage wiring for landscape lights) where it just gets naturally buried by leaves and such.

There is also this device:

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B009AGCLVG/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_ep_dp_4qRNAbR76886G](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009AGCLVG)

... specifically meant to work with coax, but claims "up to" 850ft for "in-house" coax, which cynically leaves me dubious that it'd really work for 600ft.

And this ludicrously cheap device is powered (and I have AC power at the outbuilding), leading me to believe it might actually work better:

[https://www.amazon.com/2-PACK-DIRECTV-Broadband-DECA-Ethernet-to-Coax-Adapter-Third-Generation-with-2-AC-Power-Supplies/dp/B01AYMGPIO/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_txt?ie=UTF8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01AYMGPIO)

Comment: Regarding wireless solution: just pointing out that there are devices like Ubiquiti's [PowerBeam](https://www.ubnt.com/airmax/powerbeam-ac-gen2/). I don't know that this is the best option for you but it _is_ an option.

Comment: The PowerBeam works best with a clear line of sight.  Since this is a heavily wooded area, I wouldn't recommend it unless the antennas can be placed above the tree tops.

Comment: Optical is going to be your best friend.  Something over coax is probably going to be more robust than a CAT# cable due to interference or cable issues down the road from "installation" issues.

Comment: VDSL operates over a twisted pair, which could be unshielded or shielded if necessary.  It does not have to be Cat5 or 6, which makes it the cheapest wire if you had to pay full price.  AFAIK you cannot substitute coax for twisted pair, which has an impedance of about 100 Ohms.  See https://www.wireandcabletips.com/when-should-i-use-twisted-pair-versus-coaxial-cables/      I would question the distance capability of that *"ludicrously cheap device"*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to network two locations through 130m of trees](https://superuser.com/questions/616108/how-to-network-two-locations-through-130m-of-trees)

Comment: *"I have a lead on a long-enough spool of coax..."* -- If it's ordinary coax cable, and not labeled for outdoor and/or burial, then it won't last very long without conduit.

Comment: Thanks, @sawdust in particular.  I did not realize UTP (aka. ordinary phone cable) had any advantages over coax.   And you make a good point about the efficacy of my free coax outdoors (is the issue UV, or what ?) .  Thinking a few well-placed Jacksons might liberate sufficient UTP, retired from temporary un-buried drops, from phone company employees :-)

Comment: "Outdoor" cable is usually just UV resistant.  You would need "weatherproof" or "direct burial" cable to meet waterproof requirements (e.g. laying on the ground).  The PVC outer sleeve/insulation is not waterproof..